How to default initialise non-POD object onto same address?
tl;dr; How can one make every instance of object have same constant address, and then assign it after user wants to change it?
I have a need to develop my own NULL (ish) objects, and would like to default initialize to NullFoo (in value and in address) because each time object is constructed it just makes NullFoo but on a different address.
Within context Null (ish) value has no importance, and its there to form information management for serialization (- ie its not serialized). It is still very useful in dynamic memory management to have each 'not filled' data structure start from somewhere without wasting space.
So consider the example code bellow:
//pretty lights
#define CLOG(x) std::clog <<  "\033[48;2;100;150;100m" << "created\t" << x << "\033[m\n";
#define cLOG(x) std::clog <<  "\033[48;2;100;150;100m" << "copied\t" << x << "\033[m\n";
#define rLOG(x) std::clog <<  "\033[48;2;100;150;150m" << "reseted\t" << x << "\033[m\n";
#define dLOG(x) std::clog <<  "\033[48;2;150;100;100m" << "deleted\t" << x << "\033[m\n";
#define aLOG(x) std::clog <<  "\033[48;2;100;130;100m" << "assigned\t" << x << "\033[m\n";
#define caLOG(x) std::clog <<  "\033[48;2;100;130;120m" << "copy assigned\t" << x << "\033[m\n";

struct foo{
    int objdata;
    
    foo()
    {
        this->objdata = 0;
        CLOG(*this);
    }
    foo(const foo &other)
    {
        this->objdata = other.objdata;
        cLOG(*this);
    }
    foo(foo &&other)
    {
        this->objdata = other.objdata;
        cLOG(*this);
        other.objdata =0;
        rLOG(other);
    }
    ~foo()
    {
         dLOG(*this)
    };
    
    foo &operator=(int value)
    { 
        this->objdata = value;
        aLOG(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    foo &operator=(const foo &other)
    { 
        this->objdata =other.objdata;
        caLOG(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    foo &operator=(foo &&other)
    { 
        this->objdata = other.objdata;
        caLOG(*this);
        other.objdata = 0;
        rLOG(other);
        return *this;
    }

    //required for pre-processor shenanigans (just visual que)
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const foo &);
};


const foo NullFoo;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo &f){
    os << f.objdata<< '\t' << &f << '\t' << &NullFoo;
    return os;
}

and entry point:
int main(){
    { // scope so pretty lights show
    std::cout << NullFoo << std::endl;
    foo a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    a = rand()%0x100;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}

Output:
created 0   0x5600e97b13ec  0x5600e97b13ec
0   0x5600e97b13ec  0x5600e97b13ec
created 0   0x7fff9ae33454  0x5600e97b13ec
0   0x7fff9ae33454  0x5600e97b13ec
assigned    103 0x7fff9ae33454  0x5600e97b13ec
103 0x7fff9ae33454  0x5600e97b13ec
deleted 103 0x7fff9ae33454  0x5600e97b13ec
deleted 0   0x5600e97b13ec  0x5600e97b13ec

As you can see, eac initialisation is on new address, that is subsequently destroyed. NullFoo is made on 0x5600e97b13ec and each consequent constructor makes a new address (in this case 0x7fff9ae33454). It seems that memory is allocated before constructor is even called (but i don't know how to check that).
How can I make every instance of object have same constant address, and then assign it after user wants to change it?
Working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, g++ 11.4.0.

"How can one make every instance of object have same constant address..." Different objects have(must have) different addresses by definition.

Related/dupe: Why addresses of two different objects should be different?

@user12002570 please don't jump the gun. Different objects must have different addresses, no question about it. I'm trying to control when objects become different, not why they are different.

"I'm trying to control when objects become different..." You can't control this afaik. The moment you create/define a object it's address is bound to be different from any address of other object. You can ofcourse have your own class type which might have different definition of when the objects of that class type have are considered same/different but that still does not mean that different objects can have same address.

fair enough, lets see maybe someone else knows. After all... OG data structures are made somehow. Just don't "dupe" it before those who might know answer. I am well aware that perhaps i would need  to build my own memory management tools for this.

you can make the object have reference semantics by default and only when explicitly asked for a copy is made. Somewhat like copying a shared_ptr does not copy the managed object.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai can you please provide a link into implementation?

std::shared_ptr<foo> does what I suggested. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr. It has reference semantics and if you want you can also use it to make a copy of the contained foo

Links further to gcc/shared_ptr and to boost/shared_ptr.hpp

How can I make every instance of object have same constant address, and then assign it after user wants to change it?  You could use the flyweight pattern.

@Eljay so if I understood it correctly, akin to hash functions? I would define an existing memory filled with Foo object( mong which is NullFoo) and then use "manager" class to distribute them per need?

You could either use the flyweight for just the null foo, or you could use the flyweight for everything.  Assuming the other object instances are amenable to being used that way.  You'll need another class that is the public interface to private foo, which will coordinate the memory management between foo instances and null foo.

Two objects cannot share the same address. And one object cannot change address.
To have something start with the same identical object and change with mutation... that is reference semantics and you get that with a (raw or smart) pointer type as described in the comments.
For example,
const foo NullFoo;
// becomes -->
const std::shared_ptr<const foo> NullFoo = std::make_shared<foo>();
// or
const foo NullFooObj;
const foo* const NullFoo = &NullFooObj;

foo a;
// becomes -->
std::shared_ptr<const foo> a = NullFoo;
// or
const foo* a = NullFoo;

a = rand()%0x100;
// becomes -->
a = std::make_shared<foo>(rand()%0x100);
// or
foo aobj = rand()%0x100;
a = &aobj;

One can encapsulate this in an wrapper type. To use a raw pointer requires an object with a compatible lifetime, whereas a shared_ptr does not but requires the heap. A raw pointer will often be too inflexible to use for a generic API, because the caller must ensure the lifetime which means all the work must be done in one shot (no queueing, asynchrony). So, in a case where address (object identity) is important, you would probably see shared_ptr and required heap allocation.

Within context Null (ish) value has no importance, and its there to form information management for serialization (- ie its not serialized). It is still very useful in dynamic memory management to have each 'not filled' data structure start from somewhere without wasting space.

What you are asking for something that is a poor fit for this use case. In the code in the question, no memory allocation or heap usage occurs. Every foo is either a static object or on the stack. Trying to identify a null object by a particular address is forcing a memory management strategy that is far less optimal.
A more efficient method to solve this problem would be to use a type that can represent the nullity:
foo a;
// becomes -->
std::optional<foo> a;

// this is unchanged
a = rand()%0x100;

It is true that there is technically space used to hold the foo, on the stack. However, the allocation is orders of magnitude cheaper than heap allocation.
Alternatively, one can decide not to serialize based on certain type properties: e.g. do not serialize values equal to the value-initialized object of the same type, or do not serialize values equal to a value specified by a trait type.
